# Настройка загрузчика изображений CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Имеется модель Profile, у которой есть 2 поля: `first_name` и `last_name`. Пытаюсь добавить возможность загрузки изображения (аватар пользователя).

Вот модель `Profile`:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

Вот контроллер:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

    if @profile.save
      redirect_to @profile
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])

    if @profile.update(profile_params)
      redirect_to @profile
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :avatar)
  end

end
```

Класс загрузчик:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "images/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [200, 200]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
end
```

И наконец сама view для создания нового профайла:

```
<%= form_for @profile, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    </p>
    <p><%= image_tag(@profile.avatar_url) if @profile.avatar? %></p>
    <p> <%= f.file_field :profile %></p>
    <p> <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %> </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

После отправки формы новый профайл создается, а вот картинка не загружается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется. Вы в модели примонтировали загрузчик на один атрибут:

```
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
                ^^^^^^
```

...в параметрах пропускаете его же:

```
params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :avatar)
                                                          ^^^^^^
```

...а в форме почему-то запрашиваете другой:

```
<p> <%= f.file_field :profile %></p>
                      ^^^^^^^
```

Полученное в этом поле значение попадает в `params[:profile][:profile]` и благополучно отрезается санитайзером `profile_params` на этапе разбора параметров создания объекта. До модели загруженный файл даже не долетает.

Comment: Не совсем понял что нужно подправить - подскажи пожалуйста, я только осваиваю rails

Comment: @АлександрДмитренко а так?

Comment: Да. Огромное спасибо! Очень помогли. Пользуясь случаем хотел спросить - не посоветуете какую то хорошо книгу по rails?

Comment: @АлександрДмитренко есть классический [Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/beginning) Майкла Хартла, перевод на русский вполне сносный, но [оригинал](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) свежее. И обязательно парочку книг по Ruby, вроде "Beginning Ruby" и "A well-grounded Rubyist", они обе, помнится, не переводились.